# is there away to make json return the search for one character?

Tags: json, web-services

In my Application i use json to search through web service the problem with the search that i need to write all the word like apple if i write a instead of apple i will get an error is there any why if i write a return all the food start with a`s .
the url:-
http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json&q=apple&sort=n&max=25&offset=0&api_key=DEMO_KEY

Comment: Do you mean find all words that start with an 'a'? That's something that has to be done at the API level. It looks like this one only returns the first "x" matching values.

Comment: yes, for one letter or two letters or any letters if i write ap in my application url will be http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json&q=ap&sort=n&max=25&offset=0&api_key=DEMO_KEY it will return no result error message so is it possible or not to get something like apple result when search ap?

Comment: Did you read the API help? https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/doc/apilist/API-SEARCH.md It shows that it will return results based on the most relevant with a max of 1500 results. From what it sounds you're going to have to make multiple calls until you receive all results (it shows the total number of results possible with an offset)